# Source code is different from original version?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm setting break points in Visual Studio before running the Local Windows Debugger, and they all say this when the debugger is running, with a small warning label on each break point. I can't see why this would be happening; people have talked about using different versions of Visual Studio and getting this error, but I made this project earlier today, pasting the base code from my professor into a new project created on my copy of Visual Studio 2012.

I found this when trying to fix a strange error in my program that wouldn't go away even though I manually fixed things (it was a string error that claimed I was using an index outside the bounds of the string; setting this value to 0 explicitly did not fix it) so I presume that this is the actual culprit.

Comment: This warning means you're debugging a binary that was built with a different version of the source code than the one you're looking at. It means you're probably editing a different copy of the source code, or possibly that you're running an outdated binary (but this is much harder to do by accident).

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you're properly building the code (Build Solution or Rebuild Solution).
2. In the output panel you should now be able to locate where the binaries are located.
3. Make sure you're debugging the said binaries by looking in the Debugging page of your project properties, the Command property should most likely be set at $(TargetPath).

Other things to look for. The project should be "Set as startup project", the program database option should be activated (by default). Don't modify the source after you started debugging.

Comment: Whenever I build or rebuild, it tells me that the build or rebuild failed, and there are no build errors; I checked the code, and from what I've seen, there isn't anything that wouldn't keep it from building.

Comment: Could you post the content of your output window after a rebuild ?

Comment: It's very strange; it's now allowing me to rebuild... I think. From what I can see the warnings on the line breaks are gone, but the error with the code's execution is still there... Even though it shouldn't be... although, I need to check my code to be sure.